# Google calender Api gives fatal error

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

I want to insert events from my website to `Google calender`, I have downloaded the examples of `Google Calender API` but unable to run it.

**Errors:**

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Henry+David+Thoreau&filter=free-ebooks&key=%3CYOUR_API_KEY%3E: (400) Bad Request' in D:\xampplite\htdocs\calendar\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 80`

`Google_Service_Exception: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Henry+David+Thoreau&filter=free-ebooks&key=%3CYOUR_API_KEY%3E: (400) Bad Request in D:\xampplite\htdocs\calendar\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 80`

I have configured `config.php (application_name, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, developer_key)` but still getting the above error messages.

Moreover `Calendar API` status is also on in `Google console`.What I am doing wrong.?

Thanks

Comment: Basic question, but in your code do you actually have your real api key, or is it `YOUR_API_KEY`?

Comment: yes i have changed this line `$apiKey = "<YOUR_API_KEY>";
if ($apiKey == '<YOUR_API_KEY>') {` **to** `$apiKey = "XXXX";
if ($apiKey == 'XXXX') {`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue before..
have you enabled use of `google calender api` from `google developer's console`?

https://cloud.google.com/console/project/315157837873/apiui/api

If not please `on` it...

Comment: see my question `Calendar API status is also on in Google console`

Answer (score -1):

- config.php remain original no change.
- make sure the first  used in simple-query.php is "server key"
- don't change the second ''.
  "// Warn if the API key isn't changed.
  if ($apiKey == '') {
     echo missingApiKeyWarning();
   }"   just remain,